# Trying to display different value depending on other values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-rendering

I have this conditional rendering

```
      {livematchcard.event.status_name != "Ολοκληρώθηκε" ? "Τελικό"

                            : (livematchcard.event.sport_id == 4 ? (
                                (livematchcard.event.status_id == 134 ? livematchcard.periods[0] : null)
                                (livematchcard.event.status_id == 65 ? livematchcard.periods[1] : null)
                                (livematchcard.event.status_id == 135 ? livematchcard.periods[2] : null)
                                (livematchcard.event.status_id == 136 ? livematchcard.periods[3] : null)
                                (livematchcard.event.status_id == 137 ? livematchcard.periods[4] : null)
                            ) : livematchcard.event.clock_time)
                        }
```

So, the problem is that I can see the clock time where I should but if a condition inside is met for example is status_id is 134 I get the following error which I cannot seem to understand `Uncaught TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value) is not a function`. I also tried to change the code to this
 `livematchcard.event.status_id == 134 && livematchcard.periods[0]`
where I get the following error

> livematchcard.periods[0] is not a function

Comment: I would recommend pulling most of that logic out into a switch statement, and setting a single variable to the relevant `livematchcard.periods[x]` value. That can then be rendered inline without a wall of ternary statements.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Is it possible to write switch inside the : in ternary?

Comment: @agrotis2231: The structure here is broken.  When you have `(some_expression)(another_expression)` then that means the result of `some_expression` is to be *invoked as a function* and passed the result of `another_expression` as the argument to that function.  Which clearly isn't the intent here.  But then what *is* the intent?  It appears that you've confused yourself with the structure, making the actual intent unclear.  Outside of React, isolate just this logic and define exactly what this overall expression should be resolving to.

Comment: @David ok that seems a pretty good idea thank you will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're encountering is related to the structure of your ternary conditional expressions.

In JSX, when you have complex expressions within JSX curly braces, it's important to make sure you're using the correct syntax. You can't directly chain multiple ternary expressions together like you're attempting to do.

To achieve your desired conditional rendering, you can modify your code as follows:

```
{
  livematchcard.event.status_name !== "Ολοκληρώθηκε"
    ? "Τελικό"
    : livematchcard.event.sport_id === 4
    ? livematchcard.event.status_id === 134
      ? livematchcard.periods[0]
      : livematchcard.event.status_id === 65
      ? livematchcard.periods[1]
      : livematchcard.event.status_id === 135
      ? livematchcard.periods[2]
      : livematchcard.event.status_id === 136
      ? livematchcard.periods[3]
      : livematchcard.event.status_id === 137
      ? livematchcard.periods[4]
      : null
    : livematchcard.event.clock_time
}
```

In this code snippet, I've properly nested the ternary expressions to achieve the desired conditional rendering. Make sure to carefully match opening and closing parentheses and curly braces.